# How to extend the background color of a bootstrap navbar brand without affecting the navbar's height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to extend the background color of bootstrap navbar to the background header image brand without affecting the height of the navbar? Also the color of the font turned black. I tried to override it with the font color of white in my css file but nothing changed.

Here's how I want it to look like:

[image]

This is taken from a psd file.
And this is how it looks like from my attempt converting it to html/css:

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="pimg1">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-toggle">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
          <li><a href="#Home" class="nav-link home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Services" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a name="Home" class="nav-link navbar-brand">Logo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Portfolio" class="nav-link">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contact" class="nav-link">Career</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**CSS Code**

```
   body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #000009; 
}

.border-bottom, .section-two .waffle-border hr, .section-two .b-container hr, .section-three hr {
  width: 5%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #f41313;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #f41313;
 }

.navbar-default {
  background: #FFFFFF; 
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #000009; }

.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block; 
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: black; 
}

.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #000009;
  line-height: 3rem; 
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Permanent Marker", cursive;
  background-color: #8B1015;
  height: 8.125rem; 
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
 }

.pimg, .pimg1 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.80;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100%; }

.ptext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Permanent Marker", cursive; 
}

.pimg1 {
  background-image: url(../imgs/bg-header2.jpg);
  opacity: 0.90; 
}
```

Sorry for the messy code, I'm using SASS.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #000009; 
}
```

By :

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a.navbar-brand {
  color: #000009; 
}
```

Because the following style `".navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a"` is a priority.